# Error creating mysql table with Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have researched thoroughly before asking this question including on this site.

I have a students table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
middle_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
password CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
reg_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
UNIQUE (email));
```

I also have a subjects table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subjects(
subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
subject_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
level_of_entry VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
exam_board VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (subject_id));
```

I am now creating a table to link the above tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
exam_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (student_id),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects (subject_id)
);
```

My problem is that when I try to declare the foreign keys in the third table called entries, I get an error stating that the subject_id foreign key is not in the table referenced. 
ERROR 1072 (42000) : Key column 'student_id' doesn't exist in table, even though it is clearly contained inside the the students table and the same applies to 'subject_id' and the subject table.
I am certain that my syntax for declaring the foreign keys is correct so I am unsure how to fix the problem. 
All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you forgot to add `student_id` and `subject_id` columns INSIDE `entries` table.. For now, `entries` table has only one column `exam_date`. You are trying to map a foreign key in this `entries` table on a column that does not exists, that is not defined

Comment: @Delphine So do I need to act as if I am creating the student_id and subject_id columns like in each of the two tables?

Comment: Exactly. A foreign key order does not create column. You have to create it and after apply foreign constraint. Be careful about datatype and lenght but, if you declare these two columns as you did forstudents and subjects, it would be perfect ! PS : I posted it as an answer

Comment: @Delphine Does this include auto_increment?

Comment: Not for these columns (FK)

Comment: If its working now then consider accepting Delphine's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to create these two columns before applying your foreign key constraints :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
exam_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
exam_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (exam_id),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (student_id),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects (subject_id)
);
```

EDIT :

I advise you to add in every table a unique ID column (here : exam_id).

Comment: On which column ?

Comment: I am getting an error saying, 'Incorrect table definition; there can only be one auto column definition and it must be defined as a key'

Comment: I've just updated my answer, could you try with this ? (Delete entries table if it already exists)

Comment: I now get error 1215, cannot add foreign key constraint.

Comment: Delete all your tables and create again. Use Delphine's code for the last table. It's working.

Comment: @Delphine what was it? Is it compulsory to have a primary key if you are using foreign key?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi no it's not, my advice is independent of FK. But it could be useful to have every object (one row of a table) identified and identifiable by a unique identifier : datatable, individual webpage (or slug ?), for future dependencies (what if he wants to add an appreciation represented by columns "teacher" and "comments" ?)

Comment: @Delphine kk thanks. Didn't touch SQL for some time. Need to refresh.